# convert datarow string to decimal in c#

Tags: c#

i have a datatable that comes form a excel file but it seem that it's impossible to convert text field into decimal with dot instead of comma.

i have tried using culture but result is with comma or without punctation

for example "4,65" become "465" or "4,65" but not "4.65"

strange thinks is that this code is work

```
var price = decimal.Parse("4,65", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });

price = 4.65
```

but this not work

```
var price = decimal.Parse(excelRow[0][7].ToString(), new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });

price = "4,65";
```

this is  other trial

```
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(excelRow[0][7].ToString());
var price =decimal.Parse(excelRow[0][7].ToString().Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
ar price =decimal.Parse(excelRow[0][7].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"));
decimal price =(decimal)excelRow[0][7];
string price = String.Format("{0:0.##}", (decimal) excelRow[0][7]); 
string sPrice = excelRow[0][7].ToString();
decimal price = decimal.Parse(sPrice, new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
```

Comment: what is the exact value returned by excelRow[0][7].ToString()?

Comment: hmmm so the problem in fact is not with parsing but with converting decimal back to string? change your OS locale to en-US :) ...

Comment: with comma ex "4,65"

Comment: @Selvin i converting string with comma to decima with dot

Comment: decimal has no dots ... decimals are just a bytes in the memory ... dots or commas has only decimal's string representation

Comment: [Analize this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lLLMI7)

Comment: @Selvin problem occur using datarow not in a string like in your example

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        decimal d = decimal.Parse("1200.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Comment: don't work decimal price = decimal.Parse(excelRow[0][7].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); it return "465"